# How can I place an image on a Bootstrap navbar until it reaches the max height, then go under the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Basically, I saw [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/MMdrJ/2/) in an answer to a similar question. In that example, I want the image to only have a 40px height but still be at full resolution, and the rest just goes "under" the navbar. The end result should look something like this:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

```
code because of jsfiddle link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) to `overflow: hidden`

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4CA/1/

Basically `overflow: hidden` hides anything that is bigger than the bounding box.

You could also do `overflow-y: hidden` to just hide any vertical overflow.